# Can I have control panel of LAMP on linux?

Tags: localhost, lamp, control-panel

I have installed LAMP on linux by sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
And everything work fine.

I just wonder if I can have a control panel like XAMPP or WAMP in order to turn on or restart the local server quickly. And even it has some config of Apache or Mysql (like WAMP, which I love) because I don't like working with Terminal

So anyone know that? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Xampp control panel GUI in Ubuntu](http://bhargavg.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/xampp-control-panel-gui-in-ubuntu/). Also, take a look to [Add GUI xampp control panel on Ubuntu](http://freshtutorial.com/add-gui-xampp-control-panel-ubuntu/).

Comment: I went to 2 links above but it's for XAMPP, but I install LAMP so I don't have this : /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py. So how can I apply it for LAMP?

Answer (score 1):

With XAMPP/LAMP 5.6.3-0, I didn't have to add anything new. There is a **manager-linux*.run** file in your /opt/lampp folder, which can be used to open the control panel using the terminal.
You just need to run this command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

For 32-bit Ubuntu/Linux machines, this must do:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux*.run
```

Check your **lampp** folder; I am not entirely sure what it'd be for 32-bit machines.